# Can't import module in virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, python-module, python-unittest

I'm trying to learn flask. I have created a virtualenv and am using the hello.py example file as in [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart).

For reference, the contents of hello.py is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I can run the file and it creates a functioning web application.

So now I've created a unit test file in the same directory as hello.py and it imports hello. The code for this file is as follows:

```
import os
import hello
import unittest

class FlaskrTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = hello.app.test_client()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the unit test file it attempts to execute hello.py and fails with:

```
ImportError: No module named flask.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, erm, *did* you install `flask` first? In the `virtualenv` you're using?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: He says it works if he runs the `hello.py` directly it works, which suggests it's installed somehow.

Comment: As I said, the application in hello.py works. So I assume so, unless I'm missing even more than I thought.

Comment: It's installed as per the installation instructions for flask, using a virtualenv rather than a global installation.

Comment: Ah, sorry; and how are you running the unit test? Again, from inside the same `virtualenv`?

Comment: where are you running the unit tests from? is there some problem with pythonpath maybe?

Comment: The test class file is in the same directory as `hello.py`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have not activated your virtualenv yet, use the `source virtualenv/bin/activate` command to activate.

Relevant documentation: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I've followed the installation instructions for flask and the application works in my browser (albeit it just returns "Hello world").

Comment: In that case you probably are running the unit test outside of the virtualenv

Comment: That seems a reasonable supposition, but it's in the same directory as `hello.py`, which is also the same directory that contains the virtual env directory (venv).

Comment: Being in a directory doesn't activate a virtualenv, you need to run `source virtualenv/bin/activate` command to activate the virtualenv. Here's the docs: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: You are correct - I've worked it out. I had activated the virtualenv and started the application. This prevented me doing anything else in that terminal, so I fired up another terminal in the same location and tried to run the test class from there.

Comment: Presumably the virtualenv is associated with the terminal itself. Thanks. By all means, create an answer and I'll mark you correct.