# How to properly install and import sqlalchemy in a virtualenv

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am just starting to learn flask. I have installed sqlalchemy into my virtualenv but when I try to import it it gives the following error: No module named 'sqlalchemy'.
Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from datetime import timedelta
import sqlalchemy
```

I have uninstalled it and reinstalled multiple times, I even deleted and did a clean install of python. This is very frustrating because as I am still a fairly new dev I struggle with figuring it out on my own. Any help on figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
This is my list of installed packages:
blinker           1.6.2
click             8.1.6
colorama          0.4.6
Flask             2.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy  3.0.5
greenlet          2.0.2
itsdangerous      2.1.2
Jinja2            3.1.2
MarkupSafe        2.1.3
pip               23.1.2
setuptools        65.5.0
SQLAlchemy        2.0.19
typing_extensions 4.7.1
Werkzeug          2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the activation step?

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Check this answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28551300/6124137 and then this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414437/6124137